# How to convert a multiple columns matrix into a two-column table?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, z-score

I have created a zscore matrix which looks like this

| ColumnA | L1 | L2 | L3 | L4 | L5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1.29 |  | 4.5 | 1.13 | 2.3 |
| B |  | 3.46 |  | 5.7 |  |
| C | 3 | 8.16 | 2.1 |  | 6.23 |

I want to convert it to a table of two columns, the columnA with names and the columnB with the values.

I have tried:

```
df <- as.data.frame(mx)
colnames(df) <- c('columnA', 'columnB')
```

which doesn't change the above matirx, only adds a new empty column (columnB) to it.
basically all the values should be transveresed in one column (columnB) and the names in columnA should be repeated in each category. So I have also tried this based on a previous discussion on stackoverflow.

```
df <- mx %>% 
  mutate(ColumnA = as.data.frame(ColumnA)) %>%
  unnest_wider(ColumnA)
```

This also doesn't modify the mx.

Comment: Does `df %>% pivot_longer(-ColumnA, names_to = "vbl", values_to = "ColumnB")
` do what you want?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different options to do this. Here some examples using different libraries. You can keep the variable with the labels L1, L2 and so on, and also `filter` the `NA` values from value using `filter(!is.na(value))`

```
# Using library(reshape2)
> reshape2::melt(mx, id.vars = "ColumnA", na.rm = TRUE)
   ColumnA variable value
1        A       L1  1.29
3        C       L1  3.00
5        B       L2  3.46
6        C       L2  8.16
7        A       L3  4.50
9        C       L3  2.10
10       A       L4  1.13
13       A       L5  2.30
14       B       L5  5.70
15       C       L5  6.23


# Using library(tidyverse)
> mx |> pivot_longer(-ColumnA, names_to = "vbl", values_to = "ColumnB")
# A tibble: 15 × 3
   ColumnA vbl   ColumnB
   <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>
 1 A       L1       1.29
 2 A       L2      NA   
 3 A       L3       4.5 
 4 A       L4       1.13
 5 A       L5       2.3 
 6 B       L1      NA   
 7 B       L2       3.46
 8 B       L3      NA   
 9 B       L4      NA   
10 B       L5       5.7 
11 C       L1       3   
12 C       L2       8.16
13 C       L3       2.1 
14 C       L4      NA   
15 C       L5       6.23


# Using library(tidyr)
> tidyr::gather(mx, key = columnB, value = Value, -ColumnA)
   ColumnA columnB Value
1        A      L1  1.29
2        B      L1    NA
3        C      L1  3.00
4        A      L2    NA
5        B      L2  3.46
6        C      L2  8.16
7        A      L3  4.50
8        B      L3    NA
9        C      L3  2.10
10       A      L4  1.13
11       B      L4    NA
12       C      L4    NA
13       A      L5  2.30
14       B      L5  5.70
15       C      L5  6.23
```